# Low quality of shrinked images in a Viewbox

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, viewbox

This is my resource:

[image]

This is how the Viewbox displays it:

[image]

This is how I want it:

[image]

Any way to achieve that?

Comment: change scaling mode `<Image Source="..." RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>`

Comment: @dkozl It works. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change [`RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.bitmapscalingmode(v=vs.100).aspx) to [`HighQuality`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapscalingmode(v=vs.100).aspx) against an `Image`

> Use high quality bitmap scaling, which is slower than LowQuality mode, but produces higher quality output. The HighQuality mode is the same as the Fant mode.

your XAML

```
<Image Source="..." RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
```